# 4k TV as Monitor - is there a method to bypass all hardware post processing? Can we buy third party 4k controllers?

Tags: display

I've always been on top of my workspace game.

Buying a Seiki 39" 4k was amazing, that I bought 3 in a short period (for others). I have since sold those, and am now sitting in front of a 43" 4k Vizio M series, which is running much worse than the old Seiki.

I'm curious how this all works: it seems this Vizio with all configurable settings off, still does some post processing on low contrast areas and gray on gray tends to turn into blobs. It seems to merge pixels when contrast is low.

On my screen, this low contrast text block looks like it's rendering at half the resolution. It's unambiguously blurry.

[image]

Is there a way to bypass all hardware processing? If not, what does it take to drive these panels ourselves?

Are there 3840x2160 non TV / monitor controllers that we can plug into these panels? Would that even help?

## Update: images from my phone.

It's very interesting what the camera picks up. It does a better job than I do.

The only reason I find this odd is because the display takes a *sharp* turn for the worse as we hit a certain level of gray.

[image]

[image]

I'm definitely curious if it's an inherent weakness of this panel, or if it's possible to buy a third party controller. I am getting my Seiki back, and will directly compare the two.

## Fixed, but questions are still valid.

I fixed my problem by upgrading my HDMI cable from one I took off my PS4 to a proper high speed HDMI cable.. in other words a fancy Amazon Basics $10 for 2 HDMI cable.

Every pixel represents the pixel it's supposed to light up, making everything look completely clear/crisp/renders like any other monitor.

Comment: Do you have a cell phone you can take a picture of the rendered output so we could compare what the text on the screen looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the Sharpness to 0. Check if you have any gaming/cinematic modes and use those instead. Check your cables. For example, some HDMI cables only support 1920x1080 and not 4K resolutions. If you have 1:1 pixel mapping, try that, and check overscan/underscan options. For graphics drivers, turn off all visual effects as a reference.

Comment: What graphics card and drivers are you using?  The only other thing that controls grpahics and processing is your video card.  You can turn off some hardware post-processing effect from the nVIDIA Control Panel, AMD Catalyst Controller, or Intel Graphics Properties.  Perhaps get a high-end graphics card with more video memory to get smoother 4K outputs.